# Передача массива указателю

Tags: массивы, c, указатели

В чем ошибка?

```
int i, k;
float ost, a[6], b[6], z, *t1, *t2;

for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    printf("A[%i] = ", i);
    scanf("%f", &a[i]);
}
*t1 = &a;
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Надо писать printf ("A[**%d**] = ", i);, если хотите, чтобы в строке показывался номер элемента массива
2. a - то же самое, что &a[0], т.е. указатель на  первый элемент массива. *t - это то, что содержится в области памяти, на которую указывает указатель t, в нашем случае -  переменная типа float. Поэтому присваивать одно другому нельзя.

Comment: %i и %d это одно и то же

Comment: Точно, ваша правда. Всю жизнь пишу %d, вот и забыл.

Comment: Если честно я не обратил внимание на это сначала. Сам через %d пишу.
По сути integer и decimal.

Comment: По второму пункту - надо t = a;

Comment: И еще. &a==a==&a[0]. Но лучше просто a.

Comment: Посмотрите ответ "Алексей Сонькин": там в комментах есть, почему лучше всего &a[0]. "По стандарту C++ "p" и "a" разные типы, но с неявным преобразованием одно в другое." (с)

Comment: Может быть. Но когда в С++ использую a, проблем пока не возникало.::)

Answer (score 2):

1. Указатели присваиваются вот так:

   ```
   t1 = a;
   ```

   В данном выражении `a` преобразуется в указатель на `float`.

   `*t1` - само число по адресу `t1`.
2. `i < 6`

   Счёт начинается с 0 и закончится на 5. При этом обработаются все 6 элементов массива.

Comment: Вы курите! "a" НЕ указатель на float!

Comment: А что тогда? Советую вам разобраться, чем отличаются float *p и float a[n].

Comment: хоть "a" формально не указатель на float, но компилятор прекрасно присвоит t1=a;

Comment: Указатель. На первый элемент массива. Причём память выделена на нужное число элементов статически.

Comment: @Алексей Сонькин по стандарту C++ "p" и "a" разные типы, но с неявным преобразованием одно в другое. В Си (не C99) они действительно считались одинаковыми. Размещение в памяти ни о чем не говорит - на это вообще не стоит никогда полагаться.

Comment: Бред какой то. У меня та же студия ругалась на ваш вариант.

Comment: Ну так я про С и говорю =)
К слову, скриншот сделан в студии)

Comment: В общем студия мне и сказала про "a - это вам не указатель, это вам float[6]".

Comment: Не знаю, что у вас со студией .з.

Мм? Память он должен выделить. Где и что там будет да, это неизвестно. Но выделит =)

Comment: Я прошу прощения, но что вы курите? Какую память выделит??? Она не динамически выделяется, а статически с типом float[6]. Динамическое выделение - malloc.

Comment: Впрочем да, я весьма погорячился, что массив и указатель одно и то же =) Различий у них весьма и весьма. Но во многих выражениях он кастуется к указателю на первый элемент, так точнее .з.

Comment: a[6] выделит статически память на 6 элементов типа float

Comment: М... скорее 1 элемент типа float[6]. Это говорит студия, не я. А вот первый (он же нулевой) элемент адекватно передается.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, `a[%i]`, а не `A[%i]`.

Во-вторых, не `i < 7`, а `i < 6`.

Ну, и в-третьих

```
t=&a[0];
```

Comment: Ошибка есть.

Comment: Именно i<7, т.к. массивы индексируются с нуля!

Comment: Нет, как раз из-за этого <6; то, что вы делаете массив из 6 элементов не значит, что они будут нумероваться от 0 до 6!!! И кстати, t=&a[0];

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0 , *t1, a[5] ;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("A[%d]",i);
    scanf("%f",&a[i]);
}
```

Записываем адрес первого элемента массива, а дальше адресная арифметика в помощь:

```
t1 = &a;
```

Отображаем адрес первого элемента:

```
printf("%d",t1);
```

Answer (score -2):

Вы два раза разыменовываете указатель тут:

```
scanf("%f", &a[i]);
```

Первый раз получаете элемент

```
a[i]
```

Второй раз берете его адрес

```
&a[i]
```

То есть вы передаете не float, а ссылку на float.

Comment: Предлагаю еще раз изучить Си, scanf требует ИМЕННО ссылку,
и мне кажется, вы совсем запутались в том, что значит разыменовывать.